# TBitmap.LoadFromFile for a PNG changes the RGB values - can I stop it?

Tags: delphi, png, firemonkey

I need to access a .png image file's RGBA data. I found that reading a .png image using Firemonkey's TBitmap.LoadFromFile changes the RGB values. They get premultiplied by the alpha value, thus losing the original RGB values whenever alpha is not 255.

In Windows I traced it to TBitmapCodecWIC.DecodeFrame in FMX.Canvas.D2D where it uses the GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA pixel format, which according to WIC docs implies D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED.

Investigating further, I understand I can approximately recover the lost RGB values by doing an "UnPreMultiplyAlpha" which effectively divides the RGB values by the alpha value again. This works, visually, but as you can imagine is pretty lossy especially for pixels with low alpha and/or low RGB values.

Is there a way to tell TBitmap.LoadFromFile to retain the original RGBA values?

Comment: Write your own code that uses WIC

Comment: It's a cross platform app, so three equivalent exercises for each of MacOS, IOS and Android...? Ouch!

Comment: I don't like writing such comments but there are several PNG handling libraries on the web that replace the default Delphi PNG handling library. So maybe you should spend some time checking them out. Perhaps one of the has already solved the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like that way to go.